# Automatically reject any mailman mailing list posts that contain Russian?

Tags: linux, spam, mailman, mailing-list

I'm running a small mailman-based mailing list on a Linux server, and the only spam posts we seem to get are in russian. They are automatically moderated of course, since they're not subscribed to the list, but it's still a hassle to have to always go in and clear out the moderation queue. Is there any way I can set up a simple filter that based on certain keywords will just junk incoming mails before mailman sees/processes them?

EDIT: Here is a sample mail

Headers:

```
Return-Path: <bigcheesenn@itdtrading.com>
Received: from mail.orinigal.com (mail.orinigal.com [182.18.2.185])
    by xxx(Postfix) with ESMTP id 4DB4314A45
    for <xxxlists.xxx>; Mon, 27 Feb 2012 02:38:32 -0800 (PST)
Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 14:39:37 +0400
From: =?Windows-1251?B?z/Du4mXw6ug=?= <bigcheesenn@itdtrading.com>
Reply-To: =?Windows-1251?B?z/Du4mXw6ug=?= <bigcheesenn@itdtrading.com>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <398613230.20100916194219@itdtrading.com>
To: xxx@lists.xxx <xxx@lists.xxx>
Subject: =?Windows-1251?B?w2/yb+Lo7GP/IOog73Bv4uXw6uDs?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----------U77289585814785"
```

Message:

```
From: "Пpактикa cиcтeмного упpaвлeния" <fedora.proferkin@mail.ru>
To: xxx@lists.xxx <xxx@lists.xxx>
Cc: 
Date: Tue, 28 Feb 2012 20:28:19 +0400
Subject: Инстpументы наведeния пopядкa в бизнесe


1 маpтa, 2012 г.

Инcтрумeнты наведeния пoрядкa
в бизнеce
или прaктика cиcтeмного упpавления


г. Kиeв, ул. Горькoго (Aнтонoвича), 172
бизнeс-центр «Пaлладиум Cити», 8 эт, oф. 817.

Тeл.: (044) 331-шeсть-чeтыре-14, 592-сeмь-пять-64
```

(snipped)

Comment: Do you have any other anti-spam tools on the system?  I know spamassassin has some facilities to score based on the language.

Comment: no more vodka dang that sucks

Comment: Show at least **one** example of headers. For dumb-cases you, probably, can do header-based filtering

Answer (score 2):

I'd just whip up a procmail recipe that rejects any mail matching one or more Russian vowels.

Comment: Can you give an example, or point me to a page showing simple examples on how to use procmail? I'm a noob at this sort of thing.